# Find the maximum and minimum of this set: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q} : x^2 - \pi x \le 0 \} \cup (-5,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was studying calculus this morning, and I got stuck on a question:

- Find the maximum and minimum of this set: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q} : x^2 - \pi x \le 0 \} \cup (-5,1)$.

My first answer was M(maximum) = π and m(minimum) doesn't exist, but is it correct? My only doubt is in that "$x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$". If so, then the function has no maximum or minimum, right?

Comment: @hardmath Please note there is in TeX a `\setminus` symbol, which looks same as `\backslash` but its name describes its meaning better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set in question is the union of the open interval $(-5,1)$ and the irrationals in $(1,\pi]$. So the minimum $m$ does not exist (though the greatest lower bound is $-5$) and the maximum $M$ is $\pi$.

Your first answer is correct.

$M$ is the least upper bound, and belongs to the set (because $\pi$ is irrational), so it is the maximum.

Remember, $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is the set of reals that are not rational, i.e., the irrationals. $\pi$ is one of them.